# Как найти позиции повтора заданной буквы в векторе символов?

Tags: c, строки, символы

Входные данные функции

```
char s[], char c
```

Comment: Что вы понимаете под повторами? Найти, где подряд идут две одинаковые указанные буквы?

Comment: @Harry Нет , мне дают множество символов char s[], и символ char c . Мне нужно найти на каких позициях вектора S есть символ "char C".

Comment: `strchr()` вам в помощь, например...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в этом духе:

```
char s[] = "vsjkhgvsdfvk sdfgjhsbdfjhgsd jhfjklhfsdklhkhskdf";
char c = 'j';

char * p = s;
while(p = strchr(p,c)) printf("at pos %d\n",p++-s);
```

Comment: А можно на С , а не с++? Последние 2 строчки не понимаю

Comment: @MrShef не поверите, это чистый с. На с++ было бы по другому.

Comment: @MrShef Сделал, извините. Смысл - ищем, найдя - выводим и переходим *к поиску со следующего символа*. Млжет быть предупреждение компилятора о присваивании в `while`, но тут так и надо. Ну, или замените на `while((p = strchr(p,c)) != NULL)`.

Comment: @Harry да вопрос то был не об опечатке, вопрос что человек не привык работать с указателями вот так.

Comment: @Harry а для чего 3-я строка?

Comment: @MrShef короткий ответ - без неё работать не будет) длинный - чтобы привести char[] к char* и работать уже с ним.

Comment: `p` - текущая позиция последнего найденного символа в строке. Только знаете, давайте вы сами поработаете, поэкспериментируете, почитаете - так у вас гораздо лучше в памяти отложатся использованные методы...